# Need a quick start guide to configure SAML 2.0 Single Sign On in Azure Active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml

I have a SAML 2.0 based Single Sign On working with  Pingfederate, wso2 Identity server as well as ADFS. Its also working with Azure AD SAML 2.0 fedration. But I need to have my own setup to incorporate the recent changes by Azure on using multiple certificates for signing it responses which they claim to change dynamically.

Please point me to a quick setup resouce on this as I am new to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-saml),

- Tutorials for integrating SaaS applications using Azure Active Directory
- Configuring SAML based single sign-on for non-gallery applications

Your application may already be in the gallery (marketplace) in which case there will be a script or the latter provides instructions to do it manually via Enterprise applications.